# Loading textures at random place

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to load all the game data at the same time, in my game scene's constructor. But it fails, because texture loading works only in an opengl context, like if load method called from draw frame or surfacechanged. But i think it's ugly to load textures when the drawframe first called or something similar. So is it possible somehow to separate my loading part from opengl functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem.
My solution is using the [proxy textures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). It means that when you're creating textures using some data from memory or file you're creating the dummy texture that holds the copy of that memory data or the file path (you can preload the data into memory for faster loading).

After that the next time my renderer calls bind() (which is something like glBindTexture) I check whether there is data to load and if it exists I just create the new texture and load the data.

This approach fits best to me, because in my case textures could be created from any thread and any time.

But if you want to preload all textures you can just do that in `onSurfaceCreated` or `onSurfaceChanged`

The same applies to buffers.

Another approach is using the native activity (check the NDK example). In this case you can handle context manually but it requires API level 9.

Answer (score 1):

> But i think it's ugly to load textures when the drawframe first called or something similar.

Actually deferred texture loading is the most elegant methods. It's one of the key ingredients for games that allow for traveling the world without interrupting loading screens. Just don't try to load the whole world at once, but load things, as soon they are about to become visible. Use Pixel Buffer Objects to do things asynchronously.